# Need help completing the kotlinlang suggested exercise supporting Webhooks with javafx

Tags: kotlin, javafx, websocket

In the [tutorial](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Creating%20a%20WebSocket%20Chat%20with%20Ktor/06_Whats_Next), they teach how to support real-time p2p command-line messaging using websockets by implementing both client and server. I'm trying to finish an exercise where I have the client input messages via a javafx gui and receive messages inside the gui in the form of a chat log (basically a chat room)

I'm having trouble simply starting up the gui and the websocket together. I tried GlobalScope.launch in hopes that both would get run, but only the GUI gets launched. If I use runBlocking instead, only the websocket is active.
Here's what I have so far.

Other issues:

1. Don't know how to reference the javafx label variable inside the outputMessages function, so that we can update the chatlog. I try placing the label variable in the global scope, but it only results in a compile error, so I put it back inside SAKApplication.
2. How to update the label field to move to the next line (tried adding "/n" but it literally added "\n")

```
import java.util.Queue
import java.util.LinkedList

//var a = Label("s")
val messagesToSend: Queue<String> = LinkedList<String>()
class SAKApplication : Application() {
    val l = Label("no text")
    override fun start(primaryStage: Stage) {
        val btn = Button()
        btn.text = "Say 'Hello World'"
        btn.onAction = EventHandler<ActionEvent> { println("Hello World!") }

        val root = StackPane()
        root.children.add(btn)
        val textField = TextField()

       // a = l

        // action event
        val event: EventHandler<ActionEvent> =
            EventHandler {
                l.text += "/n" + textField.getText()
                messagesToSend.add(textField.getText())

            }

        // when enter is pressed
        textField.setOnAction(event)

        // add textfield
        root.children.add(textField)
        root.children.add(l)
        val scene = Scene(root, 300.0, 250.0)

        if (primaryStage != null) {
            primaryStage.title = "Hello World!"
            primaryStage.scene = scene
            primaryStage.show()
        }
        val client = HttpClient {
            install(WebSockets)
        }
        GlobalScope.launch {
            client.webSocket(method = HttpMethod.Get, host = "127.0.0.1", port = 8080, path = "/chat") {
                while(true) {
                    val messageOutputRoutine = launch { outputMessages() }
                    val userInputRoutine = launch { inputMessages() }

                    userInputRoutine.join() // Wait for completion; either "exit" or error
                    messageOutputRoutine.cancelAndJoin()
                }
            }
        }
        client.close()

    }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Application.launch(SAKApplication::class.java, *args)
}

suspend fun DefaultClientWebSocketSession.outputMessages() {
    try {
        for (message in incoming) {
            message as? Frame.Text ?: continue

           // a.text += "/n" + message.readText()
            println(message.readText())
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("Error while receiving: " + e.localizedMessage)
    }
}

suspend fun DefaultClientWebSocketSession.inputMessages() {
    val name = readLine() ?: ""
    send(name)
    while (true) {
        sleep(1)
        if (messagesToSend.isEmpty()) { continue }

        val message = messagesToSend.remove()
        if (message.equals("exit", true)) return
        try {
            send(message)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Error while sending: " + e.localizedMessage)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i've been able to make progress, by removing client.close() inside the  SAKApplication, and moving it into the main block, and passing the label variable into  the outputMessages, which simply requires modifying the method signature of outputMessages. (I'm just learning kotlin and noticed the block arg inside .websocket() is visible inside the IDE

Comment: turns out i was using /n instead of \n